# Why are parentheses optional in Groovy only if you don't need the return value?

Tags: groovy, language-design

For instance this:

```
groovy:000> Arrays.asList 1,2,3,4,5
===> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

works, because the value is not needed.

But when the return value is assigned to a variable:

```
groovy:000> a = Arrays.asList 1,2,3,4,5
ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed, groovysh_parse: 1: unexpected token: 1 @ line 1, column 19.
   a = Arrays.asList 1,2,3,4,5
                     ^

1 error

        at java_lang_Runnable$run.call (Unknown Source)
```

Fails.

To make it run you need the parentheses.

```
groovy:000> a = Arrays.asList( 1,2,3,4,5)
===> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Is there a design reason behind this? Or is it just the way it was implemented?

Comment: Funny, they did that in Visual Basic too... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the answer historically, but note:

- the GEP-3 has new features for DSL syntax (see [Guillaume's blog post](http://glaforge.free.fr/weblog/?catid=2&itemid=293) and [the GEP-3 proposal](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GroovyJSR/GEP+3+-+Command+Expression+based+DSL))
- Groovy 1.8 Beta 3 has some support for RHS (see [this Jira item](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4401))

Your example should work with Groovy 1.8 beta3+

Answer (score 3):

because you would not be able to chain method calls onto the return value without them. (it would be ambiguous if you are to chain to the individual parameter or the return value.)